# How to specify a Preferred timezone for Outlook API in request headers

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I need to create an event on my calendar, so I'm using Microsoft Graph API for this. Since I don't want to add TimeZone every time in my request I was trying to add it in the request header, however I'm getting the certain errors such as

> An error occurred when parsing the HTTP header '`Prefer`'. The header value '`outlook.timezone=Pacific Standard Time`' is incorrect at position '`25`' because '`S`' is not a recognized separator. The supported separators are '`,`', '`;`', and '`=`'.

[image]

I'll be using Retrofit to call this API, my integration is on a Spring based application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround the timezone name with double quotes:

```
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that in the graph explorer, getting the following error :
"message": "A valid TimeZone value must be specified. The following TimeZone value is not supported: ''.",

Comment: Weird, works fine for me. See the screenshot in my updated answer.

Comment: You are using a GET request, however I want that the event object received as a response of successful event creation should not default the time zone to UTC.

Comment: It's the same for POST. However you still have to provide a "timeZone" value inside start and end.